# error in compile file in C with gcc in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, terminal

i write a simple program in c like this in the picture , it's a small code to print hello world i change the permission of this file but i don't get any good result
[image]

i get an error when i want to compile my code with gcc in my terminal i have tried to change the code but i don't get any good result

***this the error***

[image]

Comment: `void main()` your main function should return `int`!

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text when possible.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are trying to execute the source code instead of exec_file.

Try

```
./exec_file
```

instead of

```
./foo11.c
```

Answer (score 2):

You run the wrong program. You compile to `exec_file`, but you try to run the C file.

You should do:

```
~$ gcc foo11.c -o exec_file
~$ ./exec_file
```

The `-o` option means that the compiler write the resulting binary into `exec_file`.

What a compiler (in your case `gcc`) does, is create a *binary*, which is a executable file created from your source code file.